# Assembly 8086 cannot pass string literal to a macro with space properly

Tags: assembly, macros, x86-16, string-literals, tasm

I have the following macro:

```
mac_print macro string
    irpc char, string
        push '&char'
        call print_char
    endm
endm
```

(note that print_char procedure works just fine)

Which works fine if I write somewhere in my program for example:

```
mac_print hey
```

or if I write:

```
mac_print <hey>
```

However, if I try to pass to the macro with a space in it, like for example:

```
mac_print <hey you>
```

or

```
mac_print hey you
```

It only prints hey!
What is also weird is if I somewhere in my program:

```
irpc char, <hey you>
    push '&char'
    call print_char
endm
```

it works fine. So it seems as though I am not passing the string literal to the macro properly. Can some one help me fix my problem?

Comment: You want `irpc char, <&string>`. Invoke as `mac_print <hey you>`.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. Thanks a lot!